# WebdriverIO - What is the right command to run WDIO

Tags: webdriver-io

I just migrated to the newest version of WebdriverIO
Earlier was using:

---

*"./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js /test/specs/ui.js"* as command into package.json file

Now based on the offical docs can see:

---

*"npx wdio wdio.conf.js /test/specs/ui.js"*

Which is most official command in order to execute specific script?

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue. It's solved by this command. Before that check specs same as

```
specs: [
        './test/specs/**/*.js'
    ]
```

in  wdio.conf.js`.

```
npx wdio --spec=yourfile.js
```